# How to get time-stamps accurately in angular 2 from my web users?

Tags: angular

How to get time-stamps accurately in angular 2 from my web users? I can get timestamps from the users by using simple javascript code Date.now(). But this timestamp might be incorrect. Because some user's date might be incorrect. How should I do it?

Comment: If you care about precise time (or, at least, *consistent* time), get the value *server side* not *client side*.

Comment: How can I get the value in server side? I am using angular2

Comment: Why would the client side framework you're using be relevant to that? How you get the value on the server depends on what you're running on the server; you should do some research.

Comment: Try this `new Date().getTime();`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this from Angular 2 or any other javascript framework because they all eventually will get the time form the web user's machine which might have the wrong time.

Not sure why you need the time, but if you let me know what you're trying to do maybe I can help with how to implement this on the server side.